# Class 'WSClient' not found PHP

Tags: php, wsdl, ws-client

I'm using wsf/php/2.1.0 using wamp 2.2, I've loaded and enabled wsf.dll and php_xsl.dll and configured my php.ini but still I 'm getting this fatal error.

Fatal error: Class 'WSClient' not found

modification in php.ini and httpd.config

```
[wsf]
wsf.home="C:\wamp\www\wsf\wsf_c"
wsf.log_path="C:\wamp\www\wsf\wsf_c\wsf_c\logs"
wsf.log_level=3
wsf.rm_db_dir="C:\wamp\www\wsf\wsf_c\wsf_c"



PHPIniDir "C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/bin/php.ini"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

I've defined that wsf folder in envoirmental variable so this folder can be access from anywhere, and also included

```
ini_set("include_path","C:\wamp\www\wsf\scripts\\");
```

Can anyone tell me how to make this thing run??

Thanks

Comment: both the extensions are enabled as I've put the ddl files there and they are also checked extension list

Answer (score 2):

to use WSF/PHP with WAMP, let me advice you this [tutorial](http://fash7y.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/solved-how-to-set-up-https-with-openssl-in-wamp/). You need to follow this tuto until the end (4.b). Once finished, you follow the installation guide [here](http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/07/19/install-wsfphp-with-wampserver/).

For me, after several attempts, I have finally succeed in using this WSF/PHP API.

Of course, if you encounter some issues again, don't hesitate to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I remind this bug (seems so) as well. The obvious cure was to copy/symlink the wsf PHP API directory to the working directory of the script.